# Scala regex and exact match pattern matching

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

This is string regex question. The requirement is I have some kinds of pattern which is configurable and then this pattern will be used to validate the input information.

```
 val regex = pattern.r
      message match {
        case regex() => true //this will use exact match
        case regex(t) => true //this will use regex match
        case _ => false
 }
```

The implementation about regex() and regex(t) are very similar. I really want to try to unify it. But the reason I am using it is that empty bracket is for exact match and alias with bracket is for regex match.

```
val pattern = "123(.*)".r
val exactMatch = "123".r

val t = "123"
val r = "123123123"

t match {
  case pattern(r) => println("regex match") //true
  case pattern() => println("exact match")
}

r match {
  case pattern(r) => println("regex match") //true
  case pattern() => println("exact match")
}

t match {
  case exactMatch(r) => println("regex match")
  case exactMatch() => println("exact match") //true
}

r match {
  case exactMatch(r) => println("regex match")
  case exactMatch() => println("exact match")
  case _ => //true
}
```

Is there any better solution ?

Many thanks in advance